# Adding clolumns in between a table while joining

Tags: pyspark

```
 Need to add new columns with constant values while joining two tables    
 using  pyspark. Using lit isn't solving the issue in Pyspark.

\\\**** Table A *******\\\\\\\

There are two tables A , B Table A as follows
 ID Day Name Description
 1   2016-09-01  Sam   Retail
 2   2016-01-28  Chris Retail
 3   2016-02-06  ChrisTY Retail
 4   2016-02-26  Christa Retail
 3   2016-12-06  ChrisTu Retail
 4   2016-12-31  Christi Retail

\\\**** Table B *****\\\\\\\
 Table B

ID SkEY
1  1.1
2  1.2
3  1.3

 from pyspark.sql import sparksession
 from pyspark.sql import functions as F
 from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
 from pyspark import HiveContext
 hiveContext= HiveContext(sc)


 ABC2 = spark.sql(
"select * From A where day ='{0}'".format(i[0])
 )
Join = ABC2.join(
 Tab2,
 (
    ABC2.ID == Tab2.ID
)
).select(
Tab2.skey,
ABC2.Day,
ABC2.Name,
ABC2.withColumn('newcol1, lit('')),
ABC2.withColumn('newcol2, lit('A')),
ABC2.Description
)
Join.select(
"skey",
"Day",
"Name",
"newcol1",
"newcol2",
"Description"
 ).write.mode("append").format("parquet").insertinto("Table")

ABC=spark.sql(
"select distinct day from A where day= '2016-01-01' "
)
```

The above code is resulting in issues even after defining the new columns
 and constant values with lit, also newcol1 needs to take null value and newcol2 
 as A

New Table should be loaded with the following columns in the same order as 
     presented and also with new columns with constant values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your Join DF as:

Join = ABC2.join(Tab2, (ABC2.ID == Tab2.ID))\
.select(Tab2.skey,ABC2.Day,ABC2.Name,)\
.withColumn('newcol1', lit(""))\
.withColumn('newcol2', lit("A"))

Comment: Thanks Reems, answer was useful but is there a way to add the columns in between columns of a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

you can Join.select in the order you like, so your code will look like:

Join = ABC2.join(Tab2, (ABC2.ID == Tab2.ID))\ .select(Tab2.skey,ABC2.Day,ABC2.Name,ABC2.Description)\ .withColumn('newcol1', lit(""))\ .withColumn('newcol2', lit("A"))

Join.select(
"skey",
"Day",
"Name",
"newcol1",
"newcol2",
"Description"
 ).write.mode("append").format("parquet").insertinto("Table")

Comment: okay thanks Reems, I've already done the same. was wondering if there is a way to arbitrarily do the same in the same in the join only.